# How to add a common color legend to a grid of density plots?

Tags: plotting, legending

I have a grid of density plots, say something like:

```
GraphicsGrid[Partition[Table[
  DensityPlot[Sin[i x] Sin[y/i], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}],
  {i, 1, 4}], 2]]
```

I want to show a color legend bar next to this plot. I know that the option `PlotLegends -> Automatic` does this for a *single* density plot, so if I do

```
GraphicsGrid[Partition[Table[
  DensityPlot[Sin[i x] Sin[y/i], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}, PlotLegends -> Automatic],
  {i, 1, 4}], 2]]
```

I get the same color legend bar repeated four times, one for each density plot. But naturally what I want is to show a single bar common to all the density plots in the `GraphicsGrid`. How do I do this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As Cormullion [pointed out](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/20019/52), you will have to create the legend by hand as it would be difficult to have a legend created automatically by `GraphicsGrid`. However, the simplest method of attaching a legend is to use `Legended` directly. The structure of `Legended` when used like this is

```
Legended[ Graph | Graphics | Graphics3D, legend ]
```

Then, in your case, you use

```
Legended[
  GraphicsGrid[Partition[Table[
    DensityPlot[Sin[i x] Sin[y/i], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3},
      ColorFunction -> "LakeColors"],
    {i, 1, 4}], 2]
  ],
  BarLegend[{"LakeColors", {-1, 1}}, LegendLayout -> "Column"]
]
```

[image]

Or, if you would like to place it below

```
Legended[
  GraphicsGrid[Partition[Table[
    DensityPlot[Sin[i x] Sin[y/i], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3},
      ColorFunction -> "LakeColors"],
    {i, 1, 4}], 2]
  ],
  Placed[
    BarLegend[{"LakeColors", {-1, 1}}, LegendLayout -> "Row"],
    Below
  ]
]
```

[image]

When generated automatically using `PlotLegends`, [`Placed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Placed.html) is inserted automatically, so you can use it to position the legend here.

Comment: What I'm wishing for now is setting the *size* of the legend bar.  You could say, just resize the graphics grid to make it smaller, then the legend will be larger in proportion to it.  But the fonts will also be larger in proportion to it, so I don't want to do that.  I simply want to make the legend longer, and maybe wider.  Can I do that without having to create my own colour bar from scratch?

Comment: @Szabolcs you're looking for [`LegendMarkerSize`](http://wolfram.com/xid/0bdpz3g1u-uh2jzg), picking an appropriate size will require some fiddling, though.

Comment: @rcollyer Hi, rcollyer. You example is not right in MMA 10.4. The color of densityplot is different to that in legend

Comment: @matheorem right. You have to include `ColorFunction -> "LakeColors"` for it to work. Plus the second example had the wrong `LegendLayout`. Both fixed. If you want the default color scheme use `"M10DefaultDensityGradient"`, instead.

Comment: @rcollyer I still think your method maybe flawed. If you try `10*i*Sin[i x] Sin[y/i]`, the color is still the same. But it should be different now for these 4 plots

Comment: @matheorem no, the method is sound, but it doesn't cover the details needed if the function extrema vary from plot to plot. In my defense, the OP's example did not ask for it. But, I can see where it would be useful, as I've had to do it. However, a completely general and automatic treatment might be difficult. Let me think about it.

Answer (score 8):

Best I could do. `GraphicsGrid` can't read my mind at all...

```
legend = BarLegend[{"LakeColors", {-1, 1}}, LegendLayout -> "Row"];

plots = Table[
   DensityPlot[Sin[i x] Sin[y/i], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}], {i, 1, 
    4}];

Column[{
  GraphicsGrid[{
    {plots[[1]], plots[[2]]},
    {plots[[3]], plots[[4]]}}, ImageSize -> 300],
  legend}, Center]
```

[image: plots]

Comment: I don't have *Mathematica* 9 to test it, but shouldn't this also work? `GraphicsGrid[{{plots[[1]], plots[[2]]}, {plots[[3]], 
   plots[[4]]}, {legend, SpanFromLeft}}, Alignment -> Center, 
 ImageSize -> 300]`

Comment: @VLC Yes, almost, but the last row of `GraphicsGrid` is   full height, rather than shorter...

Comment: You could use Grid instead of GraphicsGrid to allow for different heights.

Comment: @Verbeia That works too, and doesn't need `ImageSize`. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I don't have 9 on this computer but how about:

```
Labeled[
 grid = GraphicsGrid[
   Partition[
    Table[DensityPlot[Sin[i x] Sin[y/i], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}], {i, 
      1, 4}], 2]],

 DensityPlot[y, {y, -1, 1}, {x, 0, 1}, AspectRatio -> 0.07, 
  ColorFunction -> "LakeColors", 
  FrameTicks -> {{None, None}, {Automatic, None}}, FrameStyle -> GrayLevel[0.6],      
  FrameTicksStyle -> GrayLevel[0.],
  ImageSize -> First@AbsoluteCurrentValue[grid, ImageSize], 
  Mesh -> False, PlotRangePadding -> 0]
 ]
```

[image]

To get outside ticks on the legend you could either enter a tick list manually, or make a tick function, or do a replace(all) on the `DensityPlot`.

```
 ticks = Join[
   Table[{i, "", {0, 0.01}, GrayLevel[0.6]}, {i, -1, 1, 0.1}], {{-1., 
     "-1.0", {0, 0.015}}, {-0.5, "-0.5", {0, 0.015}}, {0, 
     "0", {0, 0.015}}, {0.5, "0.5", {0, 0.015}}, {1., 
     "1.0", {0, 0.015}}}];
```

[image]

These ticks, when compared with the built in label, look a little high. So we can nudge them lower. Highlight the value and press "Control" + "Down arrow" or go to the menu **Insert > Typesetting > Nudge Down**. This wraps adjustment boxes around the tick label.

[image]

After nudging the ticks down you get this:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
<< PlotLegends`
ShowLegend[
 GraphicsGrid[
  Partition[
   Table[DensityPlot[Sin[i x] Sin[y/i], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}], {i, 1, 4}], 2]], 
 {ColorData["LakeColors"][1 - #1] &, 10, " 1", "-1", LegendPosition -> {1.1, -0.4}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Is there a way to place the color bar horizontally instead of vertically?

Comment: @becko `ShowLegend[
 GraphicsGrid[
  Partition[
   Table[DensityPlot[Sin[i x] Sin[y/i], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}], {i, 
     1, 4}], 2]], {ColorData["LakeColors"][1 - #1] &, 10, " 1", "-1", 
  LegendPosition -> {1.1, -0.4}, LegendOrientation -> Horizontal}]`

Comment: ``<<PlotLegends` `` **ಠ_ಠ**

Comment: @rm-rf Isn't it kosher anymore?

Comment: It's never been exactly Kosher.

Comment: drop shadows like that were popular ... in the 1980s :)