# Multiple Matrixplots with a common colorbar, but can't distinguish the values

Tags: plotting, color, legending

I need to create a group of MatrixPlots with a common color bar. The matrices have the value at different scale. Here I have written the code where matrices are created with `RandomReal` function.

```
mat1=RandomReal[{-100,100}, {3,3}];  mat2=RandomReal[{-50,50}, {3,3}]; mat3=RandomReal[{-5,5}, {3,3}];  mat4=RandomReal[{-0.1, 0.1}, {3, 3}];

plot1 = MatrixPlot[mat1, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Frame -> True,FrameTicks -> {{{1, "n=-2"}, {2,"n=-1"}, {3, "n=0"}}, {{1,"m=-2"}, {2, "-1"}, {3, "0"}}},FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Bold, 20]];

plot2 = MatrixPlot[mat2, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Frame -> True,FrameTicks -> {{{1, "n=-2"}, {2,"n=-1"}, {3, "n=0"}}, {{1,"m=-2"}, {2, "-1"}, {3, "0"}}},FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Bold, 20]];

plot3 = MatrixPlot[mat3, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Frame -> True,FrameTicks -> {{{1, "n=-2"}, {2,"n=-1"}, {3, "n=0"}}, {{1,"m=-2"}, {2, "-1"}, {3, "0"}}},FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Bold, 20]];

plot4 = MatrixPlot[mat4, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Frame -> True,FrameTicks -> {{{1, "n=-2"}, {2,"n=-1"}, {3, "n=0"}}, {{1,"m=-2"}, {2, "-1"}, {3, "0"}}},FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Bold, 20]];

minmax = MinMax@Flatten[{mat1, mat2, mat3, mat4}, 2];
Legended[GraphicsGrid[Partition[{plot1, plot2, plot3, plot4}, 2]],  BarLegend[{"Rainbow", minmax}, LegendLayout -> "Column"]]
```

[image: Multipleplots]

I have followed solution of the question about [common colorbar](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20013/how-to-add-a-common-color-legend-to-a-grid-of-density-plots?rq=1). But here it's not possible to use the common colorbar to know about large or small values from t all the different matrixplots. All the matrix plots stand on its own. I can't combine the matrices as, I need to mention frameticks to all the plots. Can someone please help to tackle this problem?

Comment: use `ColorFunction -> 
 ColorData[{"Rainbow", minmax}]` and add the option `ColorFunctionScaling -> False` in `MatrixPlot`s?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[1]
{mat1, mat2, mat3, mat4} = RandomReal[{-#, #}, {3, 3}] & /@ {100, 50, 5, .1};

minmax = MinMax@{mat1, mat2, mat3, mat4};
```

**1.** Use `ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"Rainbow", minmax}]` and add the option `ColorFunctionScaling -> False`:

```
plotsa = MatrixPlot[#, 
     ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"Rainbow", minmax}], 
     ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
     Frame -> True, 
     FrameTicks -> {{{1, "n=-2"}, {2, "n=-1"}, {3, "n=0"}}, 
        {{1, "m=-2"}, {2, "-1"}, {3, "0"}}}, 
     FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Bold, 20]] & /@ 
  {mat1, mat2, mat3, mat4};

Legended[GraphicsGrid[Partition[plotsa, 2]], BarLegend[{"Rainbow", minmax}]]
```

[image]

**2.** Rescale the input matrices and add the option `ColorFunctionScaling -> False`:

```
plotsb = MatrixPlot[#,
     ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
     ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
     Frame -> True, 
     FrameTicks -> {{{1, "n=-2"}, {2, "n=-1"}, {3, "n=0"}},
        {{1,"m=-2"}, {2, "-1"}, {3, "0"}}},
     FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Bold, 20]] & /@ 
   Rescale[{mat1, mat2, mat3, mat4}];

Legended[GraphicsGrid[Partition[plotsb, 2]], BarLegend[{"Rainbow", minmax}]]
```

[image]

**3.** You can also use matrices of colors (obtained by  by mapping `ColorData['Rainbow"]` on re-scaled input matrices) as the first argument in `MatrixPlot`:

```
plotsc = MatrixPlot[#, Frame -> True, 
     FrameTicks -> {{{1, "n=-2"}, {2, "n=-1"}, {3, "n=0"}}, 
       {{1, "m=-2"}, {2, "-1"}, {3, "0"}}}, 
     FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Bold, 20]] & /@ 
   Map[ColorData["Rainbow"], Rescale[{mat1, mat2, mat3, mat4}], {-1}];

Legended[GraphicsGrid[Partition[plotsc, 2]], BarLegend[{"Rainbow", minmax}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, It is perfect.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that Mathematica automatically scales all the values of the matrices to lie in the range `{0, 1}` before passing it to `ColorFunction`.

The solution is to define your own `ColorFunction` that does the scaling for you. This also means that you need to set `ColorFunctionScaling -> False`. For instance

```
mat1 = RandomReal[{-100, 100}, {3, 3}]; mat2 = 
 RandomReal[{-50, 50}, {3, 3}]; mat3 = 
 RandomReal[{-5, 5}, {3, 3}]; mat4 = RandomReal[{-0.1, 0.1}, {3, 3}];
minmax = MinMax@Flatten[{mat1, mat2, mat3, mat4}, 2];
cf = ColorData["Rainbow"]@Rescale[#, minmax, {0, 1}] &;

plot1 = MatrixPlot[mat1, ColorFunction -> cf, Frame -> True, 
   FrameTicks -> {{{1, "n=-2"}, {2, "n=-1"}, {3, "n=0"}}, {{1, 
       "m=-2"}, {2, "-1"}, {3, "0"}}}, 
   FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Bold, 20], 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False];
plot2 = MatrixPlot[mat2, ColorFunction -> cf, Frame -> True, 
   FrameTicks -> {{{1, "n=-2"}, {2, "n=-1"}, {3, "n=0"}}, {{1, 
       "m=-2"}, {2, "-1"}, {3, "0"}}}, 
   FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Bold, 20], 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False];
plot3 = MatrixPlot[mat3, ColorFunction -> cf, Frame -> True, 
   FrameTicks -> {{{1, "n=-2"}, {2, "n=-1"}, {3, "n=0"}}, {{1, 
       "m=-2"}, {2, "-1"}, {3, "0"}}}, 
   FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Bold, 20], 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False];
plot4 = MatrixPlot[mat4, ColorFunction -> cf, Frame -> True, 
   FrameTicks -> {{{1, "n=-2"}, {2, "n=-1"}, {3, "n=0"}}, {{1, 
       "m=-2"}, {2, "-1"}, {3, "0"}}}, 
   FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Bold, 20], 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False];

Legended[GraphicsGrid[Partition[{plot1, plot2, plot3, plot4}, 2]], 
 BarLegend[{"Rainbow", minmax}, LegendLayout -> "Column"]]
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: It is working fine. Thank you